# How can a variable in Javascript be a function, but not be able to be called?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-nativeclient

I am currently investigating a website, and have found a curious thing. If I find a PNACL embed element in the developer console, and evaluate it in the Chrome dev console, it logs *`> anonymous()`*, with an arrow next to it that reveals it's an ordinary HTML element. However, `typeof temp1` (the variable name) returns `function`, but calling it throws

```
Uncaught TypeError: temp1 is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

and calling `toString()` returns `"[object HTMLEmbedElement]"`. What does *`> anonymous()`* mean, and how can a Javascript variable be a function but uncallable?

MCVE:

*FF*

```
var el=document.createElement("embed"); //<embed>
typeof el;// "function"
el.toString(); //"[object HTMLEmbedElement]"
el(); // [Exception... "Component is not available"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: debugger eval code :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 1"  data: no]
```

*Chrome*

```
var el=document.createElement("embed"); // anonymous()
typeof el;// "function"
el.toString(); //"[object HTMLEmbedElement]"
el(); //undefined
```

Comment: Can you provide some code that reproduces the behavior?

Comment: I think the function is reference to the plugin that the `<embed>` is integrating with. If that's so, then in order to access it, it could be like an iframe or maybe by actionscript if it's flash...? What is this `<embed>` *embedding?*

Comment: Ok, I just read about PNACL and that unknown function must be the C/C++ which of course will be unrecognizable to a JavaScript debugger, C/C++--Compiled--**Apples** and then JS/HTML--Script and Markup-**Oranges**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=568448), I did filed a year ago.

Affected elements :

> - HTMLAllCollection
> - NPObject(?)
> - HTMLObjectElement
> - HTMLEmbedElement

Answer from chromium team :

> External users have not complained about it, so I'm thinking of Archiving it.

<sub>Damn I'm an "external user"...</sub>

Current status : **Archived**

Causes :

These elements have a `[Call]` internal method, hence according to [EcmaScript](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-typeof-operator), `typeof` must return `'function'`. <sub>(And this makes the bug a specification one rather than an implementation one...)</sub>